# Returning a Null Edge Descriptor in an adjacency list [C++ BGL]

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

After asking for advice on how to [find an edge in an undirected graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69830109/find-an-edge-by-its-vertices-in-an-undirected-graph-c-bgl) I was looking to adjust his function to return a null edge if it cannot find one. I know that boost has a null vertex (`graph_traits<G>::null_vertex()`) but I haven't found one for edges in any documentation. Does anyone have a solution for said problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is no null edge. Depending on your graph model you can conceive of one, but that's gonna mean you have to

- use implementation details (specifically, `nullptr` could be a good fit, but will *never* be safe to use with any BGL function)
- make your own model of a graph concept so you control the implementation details

In practice, I'd use a vocabulary type that expresses the intent. E.g. if you had a search function that returns an edge unless none can be found, I'd return:

```
std::optional<edge_descriptor> my_search();
```